# Primary key on subentity

Tags: ef-code-first, primary-key

I want to model the following with EF code first.
Imagine a car race, where multiple car classes compete in their own races.

A `SubEvent` is only for one `CarClass`, so each `SubEvent` is unique with it's `Id`, the `EventId` and the `CarClassId`.

Now here comes my problem:
I would say a `Competitor` is unique in a `SubEvent`, so the PrimaryKey for the `Competitor` has to be `{ CompetitorId, SubEventId, EventId, CarClassId }` (to be unique)

So in the `OnModelCreating()` Function of the Context I'd have to go for the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Competitor>().Key(c => new { c.Id, c.SubEventId, c.SubEvent.EventId, c.SubEvent.CClassId});
```

Is that right or am I overcomplicating things here?

---

For Reference, that's my code model so far.

```
class Event
{
    int Id;
    virtual ICollection<SubEvent> SubEvents;
}
class SubEvent
{
    int Id;
    int EventId;
    int CClassId;

    virtual Event Event;
    virtual CClass CClass;
    virtual ICollection<Competitor> Competitors;
    virtual ICollection<Race> Races; // not shown for shortness reasons.
}
class Competitor
{
    int Id;
    int SubEventId;

    virtual SubEvent SubEvent;
    // snip
}
class CClass { int Id; }
```

Comment: Model looks fine, but why do you involve Event and CarClass in Competitor. A competitor is unique in one SubEvent, so the the key/index should be on {CompetitorId , SubEventId (foreign key)}. If Competitor is allowed to participate in CarClass categories, then that is a separate relation between Competitor and CarClass, which can be one-to-many (if Competitor can participate in only one CarClass), or many-to-many if the Competitor can participate in multiple CarClasses. This is just my crude observation, so pardon me for any mistakes/misunderstandings.

Comment: @Nirvan, Well, i thought if a SubEvent is unique because of those 3 Keys, and a Competitor is unique for each SubEvent, then i'd have to add the 3 SubEvent keys too.

Comment: You don't have to combine primary keys for all the relationships to enforce uniqueness. Take for example SubEvent and CarClass. You have One-To-One relation, so it is always going to be unique. You won't be able to associate multiple CarClasses for a given SubEvent. I have worked on a few of designs and I don't remember combining primary keys like you are doing. Just wisely create associations and avoid composite primary keys. One case where composite primary keys are must is many-to-many join tables. Other than that, I don't see a need for you to use them.